# Can you open a file from a an online compiler (repl.it) using C++

Tags: c++

I want to see if it's possible to open a file, write and save it using an online compiler. The reason why I am using that is because I am using a really old macbook that has a hard time running xcode or codeblocks. The file I want to open is saved on my desktop under the file name "image.ppm". This is the code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{  
  char filename[100];
  ifstream input;
  cin.getline(filename, 100);
  input.open(filename);
}
```

When I run it nothing happens and I assume it's because the online compiler can't see the image.ppm file

Comment: No output happens because you aren't actually outputting anything.

Comment: Even if having a file on your desktop magically allowed a remote computer to open it, this program would do nothing.

Comment: Isn't a `.ppm` file a picture? What do you expect an online compiler to do with a picture?

Comment: I wanted to access the data of the .ppm so I can change the data in there

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not repl.it will let you read/write files is irrelevant; there is of course no way it can see files on your machine.

Comment: Hey thanks! So I guess the only way the complier can see it is if I used codeblocks or C++ and put the image file in the directory?